# Splunk Lookup search issue

Tags: lookup, splunk-query

we have this sample user lookup file we uploaded in splunk.
Our Look up file has these columns.
client,group,duser,full_name,email,status

when we try to lookup a user field from this search we are not getting the output.

**sample splunk command** :
| lookup testUserLookup.csv duser as user output full_name, client, group

This is not working for one specific user. we do have the entry for that user field in lookup file. we are also getting data events for that specific user where lookup is not working.